# How does one calculate this problem?

Tags: investing

What is the overall percentage gain if one invests $10,000/year for 36 years and realises $1 million in profit?

This is a compounding problem, but to keep it relatively simple, I was looking for a way to calculate a rate of return that is constant year over year for the entire 36 year period.

Thank you all for the calculations already proposed and my apologies for not being as specific as needed. Nevertheless, I am VERY impressed by the response!

Comment: To be clear, $360,000 is the total invested, and the value at the end is $1,360,000, reflecting a profit of $1M? Exact specifics are what's important here.

Comment: Welcome to money.SE, Klaus.  Can you edit the question to be more descriptive so it can help other people in the future as well?

Answer (score 5):

**Preamble**

First of all let's be clear, this is a question that involves compounding, so the answer also involves compounding.  If the OP didn't want compounding he would have said "If I invest $360,000 and get $1,360,000 what's the gain?"  But that wasn't the question.

**The Short Answer**

An estimate of return can be made at 6.32 % per annum, but since compounding at a variety of different annual interest rates can still result in a $1m profit there is no exact answer without more information.

**The Long Answer**

Assuming annual compounding at a constant interest rate, the calculation can be made by this summation:-

`$1,360,000 = Σ 10,000 (1 + r)^k` for `k = 1 to 36`

The closed form ([found by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1039800)) is the well-known formula for an [annuity due](http://www.financeformulas.net/Future-Value-of-Annuity-Due.html):-

So `$1,360,000 = (1 + r) $10,000 ((1 + r)^36 - 1)/r`

Solving for `r` yields `r = 0.0632169`, so an annual rate of 6.32169 %

***Plot of Investment Accruals with Compounding at 6.32169 % per annum***

[image]

Compounding the annual gains for 36 years gives an overall gain of

`(1 + r)^36 - 1 = 8.08631` or 808.6 %

This is all on the basis that the annual interest rate is constant, or estimated as constant.  Variable rates are more likely in real life, and we'll see how that affects the overall gain by using the [true time-weighted return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-weighted_return#Formulae).

First though, we'll calculate an estimate of the time-weighted return using the periodic investment values computed from the estimated annual interest rate plus annual deposits:-

```
1 + return = (10632.2/(0 + 10000)*
  (21936.5/(10632.2 + 10000)* ... *(1360000/(1269136.76 + 10000)) = 9.08631

∴ return = 9.08631 - 1 = 808.63 %
```

As we can see, the result matches the simple compounding calculation.

Now we can try a variable set of annual rates more typical of real life, with the proviso that the investment still results in a final value of $1,360,000.  Starting from year 1 to year 36 these are some interest rates that would do that :-

```
7%, 4%, 6%, 5%, 4%, 4%, 7%, 7%, 7%, 4%, 4%, 4%, 6%,
8%, 7%, 4%, 6%, 6%, 5%, 8%, 6%, 8%, 7%, 7%, 4%, 7%,
5%, 8%, 6%, 7%, 8%, 7%, 4%, 6%, 8%, 9.1074535%
```

For example, some of the values

```
1 + return = (10700/(0 + 10000)*
  (21528/(10700 + 10000)* ... *(1360000/(1236477.63 + 10000)) = 8.43808

∴ return = 8.43808 - 1 = 743.808 %
```

Again the final value is $1,360,000 but the time-weighted return is now 743.808 %.

This can be annualised by finding the [geometric mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean#Proportional_growth):-

```
(1 + 7.43808)^(1/36) - 1 = 6.10332 % per annum
```

So, in this case, slightly lower than the 6.32169 % estimated constant annual rate.

As we see, the overall gain actually depends on the interest rates over the individual years.  Their order matters too, because if all the higher interest rates come at the end when the investment is large they have more impact.

***Plot of Investment Accruals with Compounding at Varying Rates***

[image]

With varying rates the investment accrual to $1,360,000 is more uneven.

In conclusion, in the absence of actual annual interest rates, the overall performance of the investment can be stated as gaining at an estimated annual rate of 6.32169 % for 36 years.

**A Note on the True Time-Weighted Return**

Quoting from - [**How to Calculate your Portfolio's Rate of Return**](http://www.pwlcapital.com/pwl/media/pwl-media/PDF-files/Justin%20Bender%20Assets/How-to-Calculate-your-Portfolio-s-Rate-of-Return_v03linked.pdf), page 11

"Lastly, we arrive at the Holy Grail of portfolio performance measurement; the true time-weighted rate of return (TWR).  Although this is arguably the most accurate portfolio return in most situations, it requires daily [or monthly/regular] portfolio valuations whenever an external cash flow (i.e. a contribution or withdrawal) occurs."

Comment: The *gain* on the first deposit is 708.6%, but the overall gain is *just* 278%.

Comment: But Joe, if you have a 10 % annual gain for 3 years the overall gain is `(1 + 0.10)^3 - 1 = 33.1 %`.

Comment: 1360/360=3.78, overall gain = 278%. Your 800% is right for just the first deposit.

Comment: Hmm. Ok. But the entire $360K does not see that 800%, rather every deposit sees 6.32% for as long as it's there. Just like the 2500% percent return from 1985-2014 was great, but all my investing didn't start back then.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen - the first $10000 sees an 808.6% return over the 36 years the last $10000 sees a 6.32% return over one year. If the whole amount of deposits over the 36 years all saw an 808.6% return the profit would be $2910960 and not $1000000.

Comment: The 808.6% needs to be understood as a cumulative gain.  For instance, a 0.5 % monthly gain over a year is a 6.2 % [effective annual gain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation). I.e. `(1 + 0.005)^12 - 1 = 0.0617`

Comment: @ChrisDegnen - and that is fine for the first $10000 invested 36 years ago, but not for the full $360000 invested over 36 years, because $350000 of the $360000 was not invested 36 years ago. So the ^36 in your formula would reduce down to ^35, then ^34 all the way to ^1 for each subsequent $10000 invested each year, and the correct answer would be the average of all of them.

Comment: @Victor - if you want an average then with compounding one should take the [geometric mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean#Proportional_growth) to arrive at the annualised return. Since all the returns are the same the annualised return is the annual return, 6.32 %, but this does not convey the OP request for overall gain for which one should add that this annual gain is compounded over 36 years.

Comment: But $350000 of the $360000 has not been invested for 36 years, and that is what you are not understanding.

Comment: @Victor - Have a look at the [time-weighted return calculation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-weighted_return#Formulae).  That's essentially what's being calculated.  "The time-weighted return is a measure of the historical performance of an investment portfolio which compensates for external flows."  The external flows are the annual deposits.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen - and if you read the section "The Problem of External Flows" you will understand why this method is actually quite useless in answering what the OP is actually after - "What is the overall percentage gain...?".

Comment: @Victor - You seem to be seeking a answer that doesn't involve compounding to a question that does. ["The Problem of External Flows"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-weighted_return#The_Problem_of_External_Flows) is a problem of understanding, not methodology. Wouldn't you agree that a compound gain of 50% resulting from 100% gain in Year 1 and 25% loss in Year 2 would result in a final balance of $1500 or $1875 depending on whether first $500 then $1000 was deposited, or first $1000 then $500 was deposited? The gains are the same but the final balances are different, because of compounding.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen - then your total answer is wrong, because your assuming an annual return of 6.32%. So you actually cannot use your time-weighted return calculation unless you know the actual returns each year. In the example of $500 deposited in first year and $1000 deposited in second year with a final balance of $1500, the annual rate of return would be 0% and thus your TWR would be 0% and not 50% (as you have calculated above). Thus unless you know the actual annual returns you cannot calculate the TWR.

Comment: @Victor - The OP's investment's annual values are easy to compute because we know the compounding rate is 6.32% pa and the deposits are $10000.  I wrote down some of them in the time-weighted example in my answer.  As for the $500, $1000 example, please check the Wiki page.  It says "by reflecting the performance each year compounded together on an equalized basis, the time-weighted return recognizes the performance of the investment activity".

Comment: @ChrisDegnen - All we know is the annual investments over 36 years and the final profit. The annual compounding rate as you said is calculated as 6.32%, it is not what the actual annual returns were. The actual returns could have been 20% one year, -10% the second year, 30% the third year and so on, until after 36 years the total profit is $1M. We don't even know what type of investment it is. To work out the TWR you need to know what the actual returns each year are, because if you use the actual returns each year you would end up with a completely different TWR, which is why it is useless.

Comment: @Victor - You have a point about the time-weighted rates being estimates. I have updated my answer. The compound return with the estimated rate is the best answer in the absence of specific annual rates.